# Strange behavior when using apply with rank and order on a data.frame with ordered factors

Tags: r

I've found some weird behavior with `apply`.

Assume I have an arbitrary matrix of ordered variables

```
set.seed(4)
x <- ordered(sample(1:10, size=4, replace=T))
y <- ordered(sample(1:10, size=4, replace=T))
z <- ordered(sample(1:10, size=4, replace=T))

data1 <- data.frame(x,y,z)
```

Now I want to get the ranks for each variable. I could do this two ways:

With a for loop:

```
rankmat1 <- data1 
for(i in 1:dim(data1)[2]){ 
     rankmat1[, i] <- rank(data1 [, i])
         }
```

Or with `apply`

```
rankmat2 <- apply(data1, 2, rank)
```

So, here are the original levels:

```
data1 
  x  y  z
1 6  9 10
2 1  3  1
3 3  8  8
4 3 10  3
```

And here are the correct rankings:

```
rankmat1
    x y z
1 4.0 3 4
2 1.0 1 1
3 2.5 2 3
4 2.5 4 2
```

But why are these rankings from `apply` permuted differently?

```
rankmat2
       x y z
[1,] 4.0 4 2
[2,] 1.0 2 1
[3,] 2.5 3 4
[4,] 2.5 1 3
```

This happens with `order` too:

```
ordermat1 <- data1 
for(i in 1:dim(data1 )[2]){ 
     ordermat1[, i] <- order(data1 [, i])
         }
ordermat2 <- apply(data1, 2, order)

ordermat1
  x y z
1 2 2 2
2 3 3 4
3 4 1 3
4 1 4 1

ordermat2
     x y z
[1,] 2 4 2
[2,] 3 2 1
[3,] 4 3 4
[4,] 1 1 3
```

Comment: This is not strange behavior at all, but not being surprised by it does require some knowledge about R's basic data types and then some knowledge of the documentation for `?apply`.  If you read `?apply` you'll see that the first thing it does is coerce your data frame to a matrix. Hence all your ordered factors completely disappear and are replaced by characters. This is why you should basically never use `apply` on a data frame.

Comment: @Mammoth: Why are you using `ordered()` here? Is it essential for your underlying problem to work with _ordered factors_?

Comment: @UweBlock: Yes, `ordered()` is essential here. I was trying to pinpoint a critical bug in the `dist.ktab()` function in the package [ade4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ade4/index.html). This function calculates a Gower's-like distance on ordered factors. It seems the [R-Forge](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/ade4/) page is down so I'll email the authors directly and point them back here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested by the OP, here is a detailed explanation which may help other R users to evade the traps.

#### Trap 1

As joran has pointed out, `apply` coerces the data frame into a matrix thereby replacing the ordered factors by characters. So, the original data.frame

```
data1
  x  y  z
1 6  9 10
2 1  3  1
3 3  8  8
4 3 10  3
```

becomes

```
as.matrix(data1)
     x   y    z   
[1,] "6" "9"  "10"
[2,] "1" "3"  "1" 
[3,] "3" "8"  "8" 
[4,] "3" "10" "3"
```

#### Trap 2

Characters are sorted lexically. Thus, sorting the `y` column as character returns

```
sort(c("9", "3", "8", "10"))
[1] "10" "3"  "8"  "9"
```

instead of

```
sort(c(9, 3, 8, 10))
[1]  3  8  9 10
```

This explains why `apply` returns a different result for the `rank` operation here.

#### Solution

You can use `lapply` to compute the rank of each column of the data frame.

```
as.data.frame(lapply(data1, rank))
    x y z
1 4.0 3 4
2 1.0 1 1
3 2.5 2 3
4 2.5 4 2
```

`lapply` returns a list and a data frame is a special kind of list.

Avoid `sapply` because `sapply` takes the output of `lapply`and "simplifies" it to something what it thinks is appropriate. Here,

```
sapply(data1, rank)
       x y z
[1,] 4.0 3 4
[2,] 1.0 1 1
[3,] 2.5 2 3
[4,] 2.5 4 2
```

returns a matrix (again!) which needs to be coerced to a data frame. (See chapter 8.3.20 of [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) by Patrick Burns.The text is a good read, anyway.)

#### Alternative Solution

The OP has not given an indication why he needs to work with *ordered factors*. **If** factors, ordered or not, are **not** essential to the OPs underlying problem, then `apply`would have worked as expected.

```
set.seed(4)
x2 <- sample(1:10, size = 4, replace = T)
y2 <- sample(1:10, size = 4, replace = T)
z2 <- sample(1:10, size = 4, replace = T)
data2 <- data.frame(x2, y2, z2)
data2
  x2 y2 z2
1  6  9 10
2  1  3  1
3  3  8  8
4  3 10  3
apply(data2, 2, rank) 
  x2 y2 z2
[1,] 4.0  3  4
[2,] 1.0  1  1
[3,] 2.5  2  3
[4,] 2.5  4  2
```

(Nevertheless, better to use `lapply` instead of `apply` with a data frame).

#### Trap 3

When I started to learn `R`, I was misled by the name of the function  `ordered()`. It took me a while to understand that it creates a special kind of factors. Likewise, it took me some time to figure out the difference between `sort()` and `order()` and when to use which function appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough and helpful answer!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the extract reason for that happen to apply function. But you could try `sapply` to solve the problem.

```
rankmat3 <- as.data.frame(sapply(data1, rank))
```

The result would be like:

```
rankmat3
    x y z
1 4.0 3 4
2 1.0 1 1
3 2.5 2 3
4 2.5 4 2
```