# Why does apply(x, 1, paste0(collapse="") leave white space between positive values?

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

When I apply across columns in this example I get a white space for positive valued numbers but not for negative values? Why is this?  Shouldn't paste0 remove whitespace between elements? The context behind this problem is that I am trying to form endpoints for the googlemaps directions api.

```
library(dplyr)
stop_latlon <- data.frame(lat = paste0("via:", rnorm(10)), lon = rnorm(10))

stop_latlon %>% 
  apply(1, function(x) paste0(x, collapse = "%7"))
```

edit:  I think that it has something to do with running apply on a dataframe with different data types (lat is a character and lon is a numeric)

Comment: Why use a `collapse` argument by row? Isn't `with(stop_latlon, paste0(lat, "%7", lon))` what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes.  This is what I'm looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: Please, be aware when using `apply` with `data.frame` instead of `lapply`. Detailed explanation at http://stackoverflow.com/a/37828523/3817004

Comment: You took a one liner and made it two using a pipe. Maybe I just don't get pipes yet...

Comment: I've written the [`googleway`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleway/index.html) package that you can use to access Google Maps API (in your case the function `google_directions()`)  if it makes your life easier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Why does the white space show up?

`paste0` doesn't add white space - nor does it remove it. You can test this by just calling `paste0` on your vector.

`apply` runs on matrices and arrays, not data frames. When you pass a data frame to `apply`, it is coerced to a matrix. The main thing about a matrix, of course, is that all elements must be the same type. Since strings or factors can't generally be coerced to numerics, your numeric is coerced to a string or factor to match the first column. If you examine `as.matrix.data.frame`, you'll see that `format` is used for this conversion, and `?format` shows a default `trim = FALSE` that says

> `trim`; if `FALSE`, logical, numeric and complex values are right-justified to a common width: if `TRUE` the leading blanks for justification are suppressed.

So there's your problem!

---

#### What's the solution?

`paste` and `paste0` are vectorized, so there's no reason to `apply` them one row at a time. You can just paste the columns together directly:

```
with(stop_latlon, paste0(lat, "%7", lon))
```

In a more complicated case where `apply` really would be necessary, the solution would be to handle your own matrix conversion rather than relying on `apply` to do it with defaults. If you made all the columns strings *before* passing the data to `apply`, (or if you used a character matrix instead of a data frame), the conversion would be straightforward (or unnecessary).

Answer (score -1):

Since you are already using dplyr, a dplyr solution is to use

```
stop_latlon %>% rowwise() %>% 
  summarise(latlon = paste0(lat, "%7", lon))

# A tibble: 10 x 1
                                       latlon
                                        <chr>
1     via:1.222988975822%7-0.0916195541513781
2     via:0.159343465931011%72.13195314768885
3    via:-1.20468509249113%70.207717129395512
4  via:-0.134019685121819%7-0.912028913867691
5    via:-0.279895116522155%71.93812564387851
6     via:1.34379237820276%70.500525410068601
7   via:0.808272181619927%7-0.942578996972991
8    via:-1.17359899808855%70.126116638988962
9      via:1.1859602145711%7-1.00865269561505
10    via:1.77635906904826%70.685722866041471
```

Using a `tibble` instead of a `data.frame` by default will not convert your vector to a factor, which I think is desirable in this instance.

Additionally, regarding your question about `paste0`, it does not remove whitespace between words, it just doesn't add them when concatenating. `str_trim` in the stringr package will trim whitespace for you.

```
stop_latlon <- data.frame(lat = paste0("via:", rnorm(10)),
                          lon = rnorm(10), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


library(stringr)
stop_latlon %>% 
  apply(1, function(x) paste0(str_trim(x), collapse = "%7"))
```

Will also provide the desired result.

Comment: conversion to factor does not play a part in the error. the problem arises from the string conversion that happens inside apply. the row is turned into a character vector and the conversion includes a space for positive numbers

Comment: I think this last comment should be up with my question?

Comment: @Carton, correct. I know it doesn't cause this problem. I just thought that the directions aren't really factors, they are strings.

Comment: @Gregor Your answer to the "why" of the OP's question might make a good answer.

Comment: Why load another package to trim whitespace? It's in base. `trimws`

Comment: I can't remember the name of all the string processing functions off the top of my head. Its easier for me to use the `stringi` or `stringr` packages. There might also be some latent bias to suggest a hadleyverse package when someone is already using another one. I'd bet David Robinson could tell you if such a bias exists.