# R - Removing the first and last character of a every factor in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm new to R and I have the following quick question: 
What is the best way to delete the first and the last character of each "cell" in a data.table. I have imported the data from a .txt file in which the text has three-character separator - "^|^"?

`DT <- fread("file.txt", header = T, sep= "|")`

```
  Row     Conc   group
  ^1^     ^2.5^    ^A^
  ^2^     ^3.0^    ^A^
  ^3^     ^4.6^    ^B^
  ^4^     ^5.0^    ^B^
  ^5^     ^3.2^    ^C^
  ^6^     ^4.2^    ^C^
  ^7^     ^5.3^    ^D^
  ^8^     ^3.4^    ^D^
```

I am able to remove the "^"s column by column using the `stringi` package:

```
DT[, Row := stri_sub(Row,2,-2)]
```

It converts it to char, but that should be alright. 
However, as the data.table I am using has 46 columns, I am looking for more time-efficient way to do it.

Comment: Try `DT[,lapply(.SD,function(x) substring(x,2,nchar(as.character(x))-1))]`.

Comment: Those are character columns, not factors, thanks to how `fread` works with its default options. The answer is different for the two cases.

Comment: maybe you could try to read the file differently: `DT <- fread("file.txt", header = T, sep= '^')[, !"|", with = FALSE]`

Comment: @J.R. I've tried your method. It removes the "^", but  the numeric values within the "^"s have changed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Or to continue your approach:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)

cols <- names(df)
setDT(df)[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) stri_sub(x, 2, -2))]
```

If you want to convert columns containing numbers to an appropriate type, you can use the code provided by @Frank in the comments:

```
setDT(df)[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) type.convert(stri_sub(x, 2, -2)))]
```

Answer (score 3):

When I look at the contents of `DT` it appears to me as if the `^` was used like a quote. So, if your input file looks like

```
Row|Conc|group
^1^|^2.5^|^A^
^2^|^3.0^|^A^
...
```

you can try to use the `quote` parameter in `fread`:

```
DT <- fread("file.txt", header = TRUE, sep= "|", quote = "^")
```

Here is an reproducible example where the file name is replaced by the assumed contents of your file (well, the first 3 rows)

```
fread("
Row|Conc|group
^1^|^2.5^|^A^
^2^|^3.0^|^A^",
header = TRUE, sep= "|", quote = "^")
```

returns nicely

> ```
>    Row Conc group
> 1:   1  2.5     A
> 2:   2  3.0     A
> ```

Comment: Thanks for that. However, I get the following error when I try this : "Error in fread("INT_company_accounts_20160709_w.txt", header = T, sep = "|",  : 
  unused argument (quote = "^")""

Comment: I am using:
[1] data.table_1.9.6

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I use v.1.9.7. of `data.table`. Good to hear that this works with `read.table` as well.

Answer (score 2):

1) You can try just to replace "^":

```
final <- as.data.frame(apply(DT, 2, function(y) gsub("^", "", y, fixed = T)))
```

2) To remove the first and the last character you can use str_sub and apply as well:

```
final <- as.data.frame(apply(DT, 2, function(y) str_sub(y, 2, str_length(y)-1)))
```

Comment: Using `apply` with `data.frame` or `data.table` is not recommended (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37828523/3817004). Better to use `lapply`. Here, `apply` converts to matrix which is then coerced back to data.frame which is not straightforward.